# Can I work on an Access 2010 DB in Access 2003

Tags: ms-access

At work I have a very basic MS Access 2010 database (tables and basic forms, no special coding). At home I have Access 2003 on my XP michine. Is it possible to be able to open and work on the 2010 DB in my 2003 version? Please don't start making the suggestions of upgrading. I have an older machine with XP (yes, I know XP is no longer supported by Microsoft), but at this time don't have the money to buy a new system and new software.  Just need to know if (and how) can I work on 2010 version in 2003 version.

Thanks

Kenny

Answer (score 2):

The file format used changed with Access 2007 from using`.mdb`to`.accdb`and in order to open the file with Access 2003 you would have to save the file in the earlier format. This page has information on how to do this: [Save an Access 2010 database in an earlier file format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/save-an-access-2010-database-in-an-earlier-file-format-HA010341553.aspx)